# sas sort execution error

Tags: loops, sorting, macros, sas

I am using a macro to go through a list of roughly 13,000 versionID's. With each pass the code is going through a macro that joins together three tables using PROC SQL. Note: I am also using the compress function.
 The first table will run in roughly 1 minute (returns 2,561 rows), the second table is taking anywhere from 20 minutes to two hours depending on the number of payments on that versioned (returns roughly 118,000 row) and the third only takes about 1 minute return (600 rows). The time it is taking to run the second table is of some concern but my main issue is that during the loop I am running into a sort execution error after roughly 2 passes. 
I have looked up that this could be due to memory but my colleague is able to run the same macro in increments of 5000 with no issue.
ANY help is greatly appreciated

```
%MACRO LOOPVERNOS(); 


%GLOBAL VERSIONID MAX_VERSIONID STARTNO FINISHNO INCR VERSION_NOS;


%GETMAXVERSIONID


%PUT MAX_VERSIONID = &MAX_VERSIONID;


%LET INCR = 500;


%DO VERSIONID = 1 %TO &MAX_VERSIONID %BY &INCR;


%PUT VERSIONID = &VERSIONID;


%LET STARTNO = &VERSIONID;


%LET FINISHNO = %EVAL(&STARTNO + &INCR);


%PUT STARTNO IS &STARTNO, FINISHNO IS &FINISHNO;


%GETVERNOS(STARTNO = &STARTNO,FINISHNO = &FINISHNO)


%PUT GOT VERSION NUMBERS;


%SQL


%PUT QUERIED PAYMENTS TABLE FOR CLAIMIDS &STARTNO-%EVAL(&FINISHNO - 1);


%PUT PASS COMPLETED;
%END;

%MEND LOOPVERNOS;


%LOOPVERNOS
```

Comment: Sounds like a resource issue. Show the code that the macro generates and the log with the error messages.  Turn on MPRINT option so that the log will show the statements generated.  Are you both running SAS on the same machine?

Comment: You're running this 13,000 times?